# Implementing Google+ one-time-server-flow

Tags: php, google-plus, google-api-php-client

When trying to follow this example of implementing Google+ one-time-server-flow (hybrid):
https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/server-side-flow

I get the following error on my index page:

PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: app in D:\home\site\wwwroot\beta\index.php on line 45
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function set() on a non-object in D:\home\site\wwwroot\beta\index.php on line 45

```
    <?php
  require_once "includes/Google/Google_Client.php";
  require_once "includes/Google/contrib/Google_PlusService.php";

  // Create a state token to prevent request forgery.
  // Store it in the session for later validation.
  $state = md5(rand());
  $app['session']->set('state', $state);
  // Set the client ID, token state, and application name in the HTML while
  // serving it.
  return $app['twig']->render('index.php', array(
      'CLIENT_ID' => "ID HERE",
      'STATE' => $state,
      'APPLICATION_NAME' => "TEST APP"
  ));

?>
```

I have replace the CLIENT ID and APP NAME with examples for the purpose of posting on here.

Does anyone know what could be causing these errors? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This may help: https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-verifytoken-php/blob/master/verify.php

```
$app = new Silex\Application();
```